# Optimalization function (image) via graph cuts

Tags: c++, image, optimization, graph

I have to minimize this function for getting parameters "sigma" for each pixel in picture.

Objective function looks like this:

```
 \min_{\sigma} \Bigg\{ \sum\limits_{i} \big((G(\sigma_i)\star S) - I_i\big)^2     + \gamma\Big((\delta_x \sigma_i)^2 + (\delta_y \sigma_i)^2\Big) \Bigg\}}]
```

(here is link to see in normal form when you copy equation: https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)

Where G means blurred image, I means original image, delta is derivation of sigma and i means pixel, "greece y*"* is 0.001. Sigma is gaussian kernel size for gaussian filter with different kernel sizes for each pixel.

I want to get all sigmas (gauss kernel size with discrete values 0, 1/3, 2/3, ..., 3) for each pixel with use of Graph Cuts from Boykov (https://github.com/nsubtil/gco-v3.0/blob/master/GCO_README.TXT).

Problem is, that I don't know how to add that equation to program above (Graph Cuts, Boykov). If you have anyone idea how add this equation into already implemented Boykov algorithm, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Someone told me, that this problem could be solved via https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/optim.html but i dont know, how to add objective function, have anyone example, how to do it with this?